# Conflict in convert dialog.ui to dialog.py with QGIS

Tags: python, linux, user-interface, pyqt4, qgis

I installed QGIS 2.18.11 in linux mint 18.2 whit no problem. I can run QGIS but when I want to convert dialog.ui to dialog.py with `pyuic4 -o dialog.py dialog.ui` in terminal I received below error:

> An unexpected error occurred.
>   Check that you are using the latest version of PyQt and send an error report to
>   support@riverbankcomputing.com, including the following information:
>
> - your version of PyQt (4.11.4)
> - the UI file that caused this error
> - the debug output of pyuic4 (use the -d flag when calling pyuic4)

in `pyuic4 -o dialog.py dialog.ui -d` I received below error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/port_v2/invoke.py", line 34, in invoke exit_status = driver.invoke()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/driver.py", line 59, in invoke self._generate()
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/driver.py", line 98, in _generate self._opts.resource_suffix)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/**init**.py", line 173, in compileUi winfo = compiler.UICompiler().compileUi(uifile, pyfile, from_imports, resource_suffix)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/Compiler/compiler.py", line 55, in **init** CompilerCreatorPolicy())
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/uiparser.py", line 170, in **init** self.factory = QObjectCreator(creatorPolicy)
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyQt4/uic/objcreator.py", line 94, in **init** modinfo = plugin_locals"moduleInformation"
>
> File "", line 52, in moduleInformation
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/**init**.py", line 26, in  from qgis.PyQt import QtCore
>
> File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/QtCore.py", line 28, in  sip.setapi(api, 2)
>
> ValueError: API 'QDate' has already been set to version 1

In next try I used below commands in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python-qt4
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
sudo apt install pyqt4-dev-tools
```

In this stage I could convert `dialog.ui` to `dialog.py` by `pyuic4 -o dialog.py dialog.ui` command but when I want to run QGIS it removed from linux. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How have you installed QGIS and what were your requirements?

Comment: I installed QGIS based on `http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCcSNQL8HppF5uD2KRkn1Obw`. I want to build a QGIS plugin so I need to covert qt.ui file designed by qt designer to python file.

Comment: Write the video link, not the youtube channel, it would also help if you describe the steps in your question.

Comment: Sorry, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M0fWYrk2NRE.

Comment: I recommend you follow the steps you use officially, or compile the code directly because in your case is a problem of libraries. http://www.qgis.org/en/site/forusers/alldownloads.html#debian-ubuntu

Comment: In your link there is two link `http://qgis.org/debian` and `http://qgis.org/ubuntugis` that I used second based on video. Is there difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Mint, but I have `python-qt4` and `pyqt4-dev-tools` 4.11.4 installed from the Debian Stretch stable repo and QGIS 2.18.26 installed from the official QGIS repo and had the same error.

QGIS also ships its own build of PyQt4, which seems to cause this conflict. An inelegant, but effective way is to simply use the version of the **pyuic4** tool, that ships with QGIS:

```
python /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/qgis/PyQt/uic/pyuic.py my_widget.ui
```